# Invalid cast of IObservable, runtime exception

Tags: c#, generics, casting, system.reactive, unirx

I'm creating a helper to filter specific types of objects in a stream/observable. This is the gist:

```
public interface IGameAction { }

// Example action
public struct OpenDoorAction : IGameAction { }

// In Store.cs
public Subject<IGameAction> Actions;

public IObservable<T> When<T>() where T : IGameAction
{
    // Exception here
    return (IObservable<T>)this.Actions.Where(action => action is T);
}
```

When used like this:

```
this.When<OpenDoorAction>()
    .Subscribe(a => Debug.Log(a));
```

The following exception is thrown for the line marked above:

> InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

I have tried using classes for either and both of `IGameAction` and the implementors (eg. `OpenDoorAction`). I don't understand why I need the cast to `IObservable<T>`, but without it the compiler says there is no implicit cast from `IObservable<IGameAction>` to `IObservable<T>`. `Subject` implements `IObservable`.

FWIW this is in Unity3D using [UniRx](https://github.com/neuecc/UniRx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because there's no direct cast between `IObservable<IGameAction>` and the `IObservable<T>` even though you've specified the constraint.

You should instead re-cast the individual items in the stream:

`return this.Actions.Where(action => action is T).Cast<T>();`

And your return value will then be an IObservable of the correct type.

---

As `mjwills` points out in the comments, a helper function of `IObservable<T>.OfType<T2>` exists, which basically just does the where and cast for you.

Comment: It certainly should! That basically just does the `Where` and `Cast` for you.

Comment: Aha, that makes sense! I had to specify the source type as well, so `this.Actions.OfType<IGameAction, T>()`. For the curious, `.Cast<T>` does something to the effect of `.Select(a => (T)a)`, which is also a "solution" to the problem. Thanks!